# Как сделать ajax поисковик?

Tags: ajax, php, mysql

Пожалуйста, помогите! У меня вот php код:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['go'])) {
        $go = $_GET['go'];

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM search WHERE title LIKE '%$go%' OR url LIKE '%$go%'") or die("Поиск не может!");
        $count = mysql_num_rows($query);
        if($count == 0) {
            $output = 'Ничего не найдено!';
        } else {
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
                $title= $row['title'];
                $url = $row['url'];
                $id = $row['id'];

                $output .= '<div>'.$title.' '.$url.'</div>';
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

и html код:

```
<form action="search.php" method="get">
      <input type="text" id="search_input" name="go" />
      <input type="submit" id="search_submit" value="Поиск" />
</form>
```

И не хватает Ajax или JavaScript?!

Как сделать например:
запрос скачать

**скачать** музыку бесплатно
**скачать** через летбит
**скачать** игры
**скачать** фильмы бесплатно
  видео **скачать** с ютуба

Можно как жирный шрифтами 1.через Ajax? 2. и без Ajax?

Comment: Зачем Вам аякс, я не понимаю. Код не работает? Какие ошибки выдаются?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот Ajax код, работает у меня на примере.

Разберись и подстрой под себя. Так же была сделана задержка по нажатию кнопки, чтобы быстро пользователь мог вводить буквы.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#search').keyup(function() {
            if(timer)
            clearTimeout(timer)
            timer=  setTimeout(send_post, 300)
      });  
     });   
        function send_get(){
            var search = $('#search').val();
            alert(search);
        }
     function send_post(){   
        var search = $('#search').val();
        if (search.length >= 1){
            $.post('/index.php/testxajax/search',
            {'search':search},
                function(result) {
                    var $searchResult = $('#search_result');
                    if (result) {
                        $searchResult.html(result).fadeIn('fast');
                        $('#autosuggest li').on('click', function() {
                        var string = $(this).text();
                        $('#search').val(string);
                        $searchResult.fadeOut('fast'); 
                                                                    });
                        } else {
                            $searchResult.html('<p>Нет результатов</p>');
                        }
                     }
            );

        } else {
        $('#search_result').html('');
        }
        }
```